# 'undefined reference to' when compiling with g++

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, arm

I am trying to link my program with libjpeg.

arm-mandriva-linux-gnueabi-g++ v4l2grab2.cpp -o v4l2grab -Wall -Llib -ljpeg

Errors:

```
v4l2grab2.cpp:(.text+0xa28): undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error(jpeg_error_mgr*)'
v4l2grab2.cpp:(.text+0xa44): undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress(jpeg_compress_struct*, int, unsigned int)'
v4l2grab2.cpp:(.text+0xa54): undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest(jpeg_compress_struct*, _IO_FILE*)'
v4l2grab2.cpp:(.text+0xa88): undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults(jpeg_compress_struct*)'
v4l2grab2.cpp:(.text+0xaa4): undefined reference to `jpeg_set_quality(jpeg_compress_struct*, int, int)'
v4l2grab2.cpp:(.text+0xab4): undefined reference to `jpeg_start_compress(jpeg_compress_struct*, int)'
v4l2grab2.cpp:(.text+0xaf0): undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines(jpeg_compress_struct*, unsigned char**, unsigned int)'
v4l2grab2.cpp:(.text+0xb1c): undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_compress(jpeg_compress_struct*)'
v4l2grab2.cpp:(.text+0xb28): undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_compress(jpeg_compress_struct*)'
```

But, when i rename the file to ***.c** and try to compile it with **arm-mandriva-linux-gnueabi-gcc** (instead of g++) everything **works**!

I really need to use it inside C++ code.
How can I compile this code with **g++**?

Comment: Sounds like libjpeg was misbuilt.

Comment: C-style function declarations need to be inside an `extern "C"` block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are including a C header without C++ support. Try including the relevant header from within an `extern "C"` block:

```
extern "C" {
#include <jpeglib.h>
}
```

(since you didn't post any code I'm not sure which header you try to include and just guessed `<jpeglib.h>`).

In case you need to include `<jpeglib.h>` from a header which should also be viable to be included from C, you'd wrap it with a test for C++:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <jpeglib.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```